# Completion block in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying add a nullable completion block to a custom function

```
func disPlayAlertMessage(titleMessage:String, alertMsg:String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil){

        AlertMessage.alertMessageController = UIAlertController(title: titleMessage, message:
            alertMsg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        AlertMessage.alertMessageController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
        if completion == nil {
            controller.presentViewController(AlertMessage.alertMessageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            controller.presentViewController(AlertMessage.alertMessageController, animated: true, completion: {
                completion!()
            })
        }
        return

    }
```

When I am trying to call the above function like below

```
AlertMessage(controller: self).disPlayAlertMessage(CustomAlertMessages.AlertTitle, alertMsg: CustomAlertMessages.DOANoUpdate, completion: { () -> Void in
                {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            })
```

The completion block is always nil.

Comment: can you add print-s before controller.presentViewController ? to make sure the value is really nil and its no the issue that controller is not calling it

Comment: when I run this it goes to the nil section, so obviously completion is nil

Comment: did you set a breakpoint or you are assuming this because completion is not called?

Comment: I tried with break point also

Comment: The method seems correct, there is some other issue. I copied your code and added in a playground and it is working: `func disPlayAlertMessage(titleMessage:String, alertMsg:String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil){
    print (titleMessage + alertMsg);
    completion!()
}


disPlayAlertMessage("Midhun", alertMsg: "MP") { () -> Void in
    print("Yes Working")
}`

Comment: Try to remove the default value of the argument and debug again.

Comment: @MidhunMP sorry i am using swift 1.2 can u please update your code

Comment: @t4nhpt I need it to be nullable? or am I doing the nullable thing wrongly?

Comment: @MidhunMP I tried your code, but not working (converted to swift 1.2)

Comment: @vinbhai4u: I'm using Swift 2.0, I wanted to help you, but unfortunately I don't have swift 1.2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Tested with Swift 2.0 only..

You should change your completion parameter.

Example:

```
func Test( completion: () -> () = {_ in }) {

    completion()
}
```

This function can be called in two different ways:

```
Test() // Nothing happens
Test({ print("Completed") }) // Prints Completed
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you define a nil'able completion

```
func function(completion: (Void -> Void)? = nil) {
  completion?()
}
```

There are a few different ways in which you can call it

```
function() //without any argument

function({ //with parens and braces
  print("I will get called")
})

function() { //with parens and braces
  print("I will get called")
}

function { //without parens
  print("I will get called")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void

func yourCompletionBlockName(completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

         //code
        let flag = true

        completionHandler(flag)
    }
```

call completion block whenever you need

```
yourCompletionBlockName(completionHandler: { (success) -> Void in

                        if success {
                        } else {
                        }
})
```